# Looping over files and plotting (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, plot

My data is look like as in the picture. All of my datas are in .txt format and my aim is to loop over files and plot them. First row represents my variables 
(WL, ABS, T%) so firstly I need to delete them before proceeding.

```
with open('Desktop/100-3.txt', 'r') as f:
data = f.read().splitlines(True)
with open('Desktop/100-3.txt', 'w') as f:
f.writelines(data[1:])
```

Probably it would not be necessary but I am very new in Numpy. Basically the algorithm will be as follows:

1. Read all the .txt files
2. Plot T% versus WL, plot ABS versus WL, save. (WL -> x variable)
3. Continue for the next file, .. (two graphs for every .txt file)
4. Then finish the loop, exit.

[data  looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOvbi.jpg)

**What I've tried**

```
from numpy import loadtxt
import os
dizin = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
for i in dizin:
  if i.endswith('.txt'):
   data = loadtxt("??",float)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For data files like this I would prefer [np.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) over np.loadtxt, it has many useful options you can look up in the docs. The [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module is also nice to iterate over directories with wildcards as filters:

```
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# loop over all files in the current directory ending with .txt
for fname in glob("./*.txt"):
    # read file, skip header (1 line) and unpack into 3 variables
    WL, ABS, T = np.genfromtxt(fname, skip_header=1, unpack=True)

    # first plot
    plt.plot(WL, T)
    plt.xlabel('WL')
    plt.ylabel('T%')
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()

    # second plot
    plt.plot(ABS, T)
    plt.xlabel('WL')
    plt.ylabel('ABS')
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
```

The next step would be to do some research on matplotlib to make the plots look better.

Please let me know if the code does not work, I'll try to fix it then.

EDIT: Added plt.clf() to clear the figure before creating a new one.

Comment: The result is in here: http://postimg.org/image/r6u0kajib/

Even though this code is very good that is not quite what I'm looking for. I want to save two figure for every text file separately. Can we improve it for that?

Comment: Some helpful information has given in here: stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/

Comment: I forgot to reset the plot after each iteration, so I added plt.clf() after each plt.show().

Comment: StopIteration error occured (Just copied the code you have shared)

1466     # Skip the first `skip_header` rows
   1467     for i in range(skip_header):
-> 1468         next(fhd)
   1469 
   1470     # Keep on until we find the first valid values

Comment: I don't exactly know but that sounds like it tried to read an empty .txt file. Are you sure you only have .txt files with data in it in the directory where you execute your script?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.
Link to files : https://www.dropbox.com/s/a5mzgopi0wl2ey7/datas.rar?dl=0

Comment: I downloaded the files, executed the script in Python 2 and 3 and it works in both without error and with two separate plots for each file.
I installed Python via Anaconda on Windows (and I really recommend this if you are into data science).

Comment: It is worked. Great job. Lastly I'd like ask for pylab.savefig('1.png'). How can I improve it for saving all pictures to the same folder? BTW, thanks for suggestion, in the end I found a really good editor for Data Science.

Comment: In addition to my last comment: Naming would be a problem when it is a large collection of files. So for each file I need to save different version. I mean for example, for file 1.txt --> 1t.png and 1a.png

Comment: You can save plots either by clicking on the save icon when the plot is displayed or by calling plt.savefig(filename) either before or after plt.show(). If you want to save into a folder let the filename be 'folder/filename' but you have to either create the folder by hand or by using a python module like `os`.
The filename argument for savefig is just a string so you can do something like: `plt.savefig('folder/file%d.png' % n)` with a n that you count up after each plot.

Comment: Much obliged! @deepfriedcyanide