# How to plot a high resolution graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've used matplotlib for plotting some experimental results (discussed it in here: [Looping over files and plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676294/looping-over-files-and-plotting-python/). However, saving the picture by clicking right to the image gives very bad quality / low resolution images.

```
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

# loop over all files in the current directory ending with .txt
for fname in glob("./*.txt"):
    # read file, skip header (1 line) and unpack into 3 variables
    WL, ABS, T = np.genfromtxt(fname, skip_header=1, unpack=True)

    # first plot
    plt.plot(WL, T, label='BN', color='blue')

    plt.xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
    plt.xlim(200,1000)
    plt.ylim(0,100)
    plt.ylabel('Transmittance, %')
    mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
    #plt.legend(loc='lower center')
    plt.title('')
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()


    # second plot
    plt.plot(WL, ABS, label='BN', color='red')
    plt.xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
    plt.xlim(200,1000)
    plt.ylabel('Absorbance, A')
    mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})
    #plt.legend()
    plt.title('')
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
```

Example graph of what I'm looking for: [example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNSoO.png)

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You can use [`savefig()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig) to export to an image file:

```
plt.savefig('filename.png')
```

In addition, you can specify the `dpi` argument to some scalar value, for example:

```
plt.savefig('filename.png', dpi=300)
```

Comment: I can't specify filename like that. The script goes through files in 'fname in glob("./*.txt")'.

Comment: call the file whatever you like

Comment: It will overwrite the datas' and will give only two picture. Doesn't it? My aim is to get two graph for each text file.

Comment: So you can do something like `plt.savefig(fname + 'Graph1.png')` and `plt.savefig(fname + 'Graph2.png')`

Comment: Great! plt.savefig(fname + 'Graph1a.png', dpi=600) for first graph, and plt.savefig(fname + 'Graph1a.png', dpi=600) for the second solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: matplotlib.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 300

Comment: Setting dpi=300, for me, looks almost the same as the output from plt.show()

Comment: Make sure you put savefig before plt.show(). Otherwise, your saved image will be blank..

Comment: this adds a bunch of white space around the figure, to fix this I had to add `bbox_inches="tight"` to `plt.savefig()`

Answer (score 91):

Use [`plt.figure(dpi=1200)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html) before all your `plt.plot...` and at the end use [`plt.savefig(...)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html).

Comment: @deepfriedcyanide  helped me in my old question by saying:

"_The filename argument for savefig is just a string so you can do something like: plt.savefig('folder/file%d.png' % n) with a n that you count up after each plot._" 
But I don't get yet the idea. Where should I put this codes in my script and how?

Comment: Great, now can produce publication quality figs in a Jupyter notebook. running on a server, and can then just right click and "save as". Perfect! No need for `plt.savefig(...)`

Answer (score 46):

For future readers who found this question while trying to save high resolution images from matplotlib as I am, I have tried some of the answers above and elsewhere, and summed them up here.

**Best result**: `plt.savefig('filename.pdf')`

and then converting this pdf to a png on the command line so you can use it in powerpoint:

`pdftoppm -png -r 300 filename.pdf filename`

OR simply opening the pdf and cropping to the image you need in adobe, saving as a png and importing the picture to powerpoint

**Less successful test #1**: `plt.savefig('filename.png', dpi=300)`

This does save the image at a bit higher than the normal resolution, but it isn't high enough for publication or some presentations. Using a dpi value of up to 2000 still produced blurry images when viewed close up.

**Less successful test #2**: `plt.savefig('filename.pdf')`

This cannot be opened in Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 (so no powerpoint), same with Google Slides.

**Less successful test #3**: `plt.savefig('filename.svg')`

This also cannot be opened in powerpoint or Google Slides, with the same issue as above.

**Less successful test #4**: `plt.savefig('filename.pdf')`

and then converting to png on the command line:

`convert -density 300 filename.pdf filename.png`

but this is still too blurry when viewed close up.

**Less successful test #5**: `plt.savefig('filename.pdf')`

and opening in GIMP, and exporting as a high quality png (increased the file size from ~100 KB to ~75 MB)

**Less successful test #6**: `plt.savefig('filename.pdf')`

and then converting to jpeg on the command line:

`pdfimages -j filename.pdf filename`

This did not produce any errors but did not produce an output on Ubuntu even after changing around several parameters.

Comment: `.pdf` was best quality for me as well. Pretty much perfect quality zoomed in all the way so like 4k. Instead of converting on command line, taking a screenshot of the .pdf is good enough for me and saving that to a png.

Answer (score 32):

You can save your graph as svg for a lossless quality:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

x = range(10)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,x)
plt.savefig("graph.svg")
```

Comment: You could also save as PDF `plt.savefig("graph.pdf")` which is also lossless

Answer (score 20):

For saving the graph:

`matplotlib.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 300`

For displaying the graph when you use `plt.show()`:

`matplotlib.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 100`

Just add them at the top

Comment: Finally, an answer as for DISPLAYING a high res figure, not saving one. This is very useful in cases you want to display a pre-saved figure without having the data to plot and save it again.

Comment: You can also specify it in `plt`, if that is what you are using. Like so:
`plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 100` I also find it helpful to specify figsize at the same time: `plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=(5,3)`

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your *for()* loop, you can use the `savefig()` function instead of *plt.show()* and set the name, dpi and format of your figure.

E.g. 1000 dpi and eps format are quite a good quality, and if you want to save every picture at folder *./* with names 'Sample1.eps', 'Sample2.eps', etc. you can just add the following code:

```
for fname in glob("./*.txt"):
    # Your previous code goes here
    [...]

    plt.savefig("./{}.eps".format(fname), bbox_inches='tight', format='eps', dpi=1000)
```

Comment: EPS is a vector graphics format and should therefore be already lossless. The DPI makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

In My Opinion,
the best way to do so, is to use `%matplotlib notebook` magic function.

I have tried all above ways and the drawback of increasing dpi is that the figure size or say the plot window size gets increased with it, which is not desired.

If you are looking to get best resolution within your figure size without tweaking dpi, go for the magic function.

Also you can turn off the interaction of the plot just by clicking the button on it.