# image quality on matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I overlay an image over another and the result is as shown on the image below:

Left is the default image with the blue part missing in some quality details. Right is the zoom in of the blue part

[image]

Is there a way to improve the image quality details on matlibplot? It is currently missing the black border details. It is actually there when the image is zoom in.

Thanks for helping out.

replying to comment below. I tried svg:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# imbg is layout/ background
imbg = plt.imread(r"templates\stackflow\background.svg")
# imfg is furniture/ foreground
desk1200 = plt.imread(r"templates\stackflow\SPOT.svg")

# manually set aspect dimension for background
ext= [0,20,0,16]

desk1200_x= 1.2
desk1200_y= 1.85

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(imbg, zorder= 0, extent=ext )
ax.imshow(desk1200, zorder= 1, extent=[5,5+desk1200_x,5,5+desk1200_y])
ax.axis(ext)

plt.xlabel("size", fontsize= 12)
plt.title('Proposed', fontsize= 20)

plt.show()
```

but got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imageoverlay2.py", line 4, in <module>
    imbg = plt.imread(r"templates\stackflow\background.svg")
  File "\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2233, in imread
    return _imread(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1280, in imread
    im = pilread(fname)
  File "\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1258, in pilread
    with Image.open(fname) as image:
  File "\Python\Python36\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2572, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
OSError: cannot identify image file 'templates\\stackflow\\background.svg'
```

Comment: Have you tried [changing the dpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870642/matplotlib-how-to-plot-a-high-resolution-graph) of the saved picture? Or even saving it in .svg?

Comment: Yes, I tried svg but got error. I updated in question above.

Comment: You cannot load svg images into matplotlib. That is simply not possible. What the comment above suggests is to change the dpi of the output, e.g. `plt.subplots(dpi=300)` or to **save** the output as svg.

Comment: matplotlib (actually PIL) dont support read SVG file, full support list is [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html), you may use EPS.

Comment: Replying to @georgexsh, i change the file format to EPS but there is still error. Is there a different way to open EPS file using matplotlib?

Comment: @E.001 you may need to install Ghostscript.

Comment: see this [link](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#eps) of PIL doc