# Why same Expression gets different graph by using matplotlib and mathematica？

Tags: matplotlib, wolfram-mathematica

Outputs of two tools(matplotlib and mathematica) of same expressions are so different!It's so strange.

- python3.6: matplotlib
- mathematica: https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com

*matplotlib:*

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

fig = plot.figure()
fig.add_subplot(211, projection='polar')
# Set the title of the polar plot
plot.title('graph')

# Radian values upto 2*pi
radians = np.arange(0, (2*np.pi), 0.01)

for radian in radians:
    # Plot in polar co-ordinates
    plot.polar(radian, np.sin(radian) + np.power(np.sin(3*radian), 3),'o')

# Display the Polar plot
plot.show()
```

*mathematica:*

```
PolarPlot[{t, Sin[t] + Sin[3 t]^3}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

---

graph of matplotlib:

[image: KkLwT0.png]

graph of mathematica:

[image: KkLdwq.png]

Comment: The reason for the blue arc in the Mathematica plot that is not present in the mathplotlib plot is a misunderstanding of the syntax of `PolarPlot` in Mathematica. Try `PolarPlot[Sin[t]+Sin[3 t]^3,{t,0,2 Pi}]` and that will show the curve above the horizontal axis without the blue arc. That still does not explain the curve below the horizontal axis in mathplotlib.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870642/matplotlib-how-to-plot-a-high-resolution-graph

Comment: It doesn't help. Thx anyway.