# Blurry Matplotlib figure in Tkinter on a Mac retina display

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I embedded a Matplotlib figure in a tkinter window running on macOS. However, my MacBook Pro has a retina (high resolution) display which makes the Matplotlib figure look blurry. I tried to scale the app using `app.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 2.0)` but it made the plot figure too large to display in the window. How do I embed a Matplotlib figure at high resolution to support the retina display on a Mac? Is it possible to embed a Matplotlib figure as a vector graphic (SVG, PDF) to avoid resolution issues?

[image: tkinter matplotlib figure]

```py
import tkinter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

class App(tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Tkinter Matplotlib Demo')

        # Data to plot
        data = [3, 4, 2, 8, 7, 10]

        # Create plot and figure
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
        ax.plot(data)
        ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
        ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')

        # Create FigureCanvasTkAgg object
        figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)

        # Create the Matplotlib toolbar
        NavigationToolbar2Tk(figure_canvas, self)

        figure_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.geometry('600x400')
    app.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 2.0)
    app.mainloop()
```

### Approach #2

I tried to use the Matplotlib macosx backend but it reports an error related to NSButton and terminates the app.

```py
import tkinter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_macosx import (FigureCanvasMac, NavigationToolbar2Mac)

class App(tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Tkinter Matplotlib Demo')

        # Data to plot
        data = [3, 4, 2, 8, 7, 10]

        # Create plot and figure
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=100)
        ax.plot(data)
        ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
        ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')

        # Create FigureCanvasTkAgg object
        figure_canvas = FigureCanvasMac(fig)

        # Create the Matplotlib toolbar
        NavigationToolbar2Mac(figure_canvas)

        figure_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I do not know if this is also a Mac problem but recently, I had to downgrade for test purposes to matplotlib 3.3. and was rather surprised how grainy the output was in comparison to that of 3.5. I assume you already use the latest version?

Comment: @Mr.T Yes, I am using Matplotlib version 3.5 which is currently the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dpi is still set to 100.  Try moving that up to 1200.  There was a similar problem here: [Matplotlib - How to plot a high resolution graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870642/matplotlib-how-to-plot-a-high-resolution-graph)

Comment: Setting the dpi to 1200 makes the figure look worse than in my example. And by worse I mean its size is too large to display in the window.