# How to save a heat map with excellent quality?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to save a heat map in a high resolution quality, how can I do that? I've tried the following code, however, it's giving me an incomplete figure with a poor resolution as attached. Thanks.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9cQJ.jpg)

Update 1: I think the quality can be enhanced by adding the "dpi" option, however, the figure is still incomplete, why?

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("bmh")
#sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
x = x.pivot("Design Parameter","No. of Studies",'No. of Studies')
ax = sns.heatmap(x, cmap="YlGnBu",linewidths=.5)
fig1=ax.figure
fig1.savefig("Design parameters.tiff") #save as jpg```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib - How to plot a high resolution graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870642/matplotlib-how-to-plot-a-high-resolution-graph)

Comment: Thanks for posting, yes I've figured this out after seconds of posting the question, yet my plot is incomplete, why? Thanks again.

Comment: It can happen sometimes. Give a try to `bbox_inches='tight'` (source: [Matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig)).